# jQuery click function not working after updating class

Tags: jquery

Once I change element's class using jQuery, the click function does not work on the new class.

Here is my code

```
jQuery('.close').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('div').slideUp();
    jQuery(this).addClass('open');
    jQuery(this).removeClass('close');
});


jQuery('.open').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('div').slideDown();
    jQuery(this).addClass('close');
    jQuery(this).removeClass('open');
});​
```

You can try it here - http://jsfiddle.net/NkG9k/1/

Try clicking on the toggle button again. (it won't slidedown the div)

Comment: The reason I posted it as a comment as that it's not strictly the most efficient way to do it. It will work but I'm sure others will come up with a better solution. I would probably go with @Prog Mania and specify another selector to the element such as giving it an ID.

Comment: jQuery live() is depreciated and should not be used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this, Apply `on` on document and use class filter to attach the event to your button.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/NkG9k/2/)**

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.close', function() {
    jQuery('div').slideUp();
    jQuery(this).addClass('open');
    jQuery(this).removeClass('close');
});


jQuery(document).on('click','.open', function() {
    jQuery('div').slideDown();
    jQuery(this).addClass('close');
    jQuery(this).removeClass('open');
});​
```

You need to delegate event on static parent of the element you want this dynamic behavior so that when the class is changed (from `open` to `close` and from `close` to `open`) of an element the event is bind automatically on this element according to newly changed class.

[Understanding Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.

Answer (score 1):

you've removed the class that is triggering the event.
you may give it an id and call it with id instead of class.

[check this](http://jsfiddle.net/NkG9k/9/)

```
    jQuery('#close').toggle( function() {
    jQuery('div').slideUp();
    jQuery(this).addClass('open');
    jQuery(this).removeClass('close');
},function() {
    jQuery('div').slideDown();
    jQuery(this).addClass('close');
    jQuery(this).removeClass('open');
});
<div id="close" class="close">toggle</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('.close').bind('click', function() {
 $('div').toggle();
});
```

If you need the animation you can check out this [link](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 0):

if you want use to code below.

```
<button class="toggle">toggle</button> 
<div>THIS IS TEXT</div>


jQuery('.toggle').toggle( 
    function() {
        jQuery('div').slideUp();
    },
    function() {
        jQuery('div').slideDown();
    }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use live event instead of click as live event works when the element is created

```
jQuery('.close').live('click', function() {
    jQuery('div').slideUp();
    jQuery(this).addClass('open');
    jQuery(this).removeClass('close');
});


jQuery('.open').live('click', function() {
    jQuery('div').slideDown();
    jQuery(this).addClass('close');
    jQuery(this).removeClass('open');
});​
```

Comment: jQuery live() is depreciated and should not ever be used.

Comment: @logard why live() is deprecated now?

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()."  [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/live/)